# How to share project dependencies among multiple projects in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have the below project structure

```
Main Project
--Sub Project 1
    - child 1
        * pom-child1
    - child 2
        * pom-child2
  * pom-sub-project1

--Sub Project 2
      * pom-sub-project2
* main project pom
```

I had defined few project dependencies in main project pom and referred it in child and sub project poms. But I am finding issues if the pom is not a direct child of the main project pom. Is there a way to resolve it?

Example, 
Main Project pom

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>dev</version>
<name>parent-project</name>
..
<properties><spring-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring-version></properties>
```

child POM

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.test.pkg</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-proj</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </parent>
```

The ${project.version} isn't resolved if it is not a direct child of a parent pom due to which none of the project dependencies are resolved.

Also, I read about **properties-maven-plugin** which is used to read properties from external properties file. Can this be used for reading dependency version or is there any other plugin/approach that could be used in this case?

Comment: is main project pom also defined as parent of sub-project 1 and 2? are sub projects defined as parent of child projects? what type of issue are you encountering?

Comment: Which connection doesn't work? Between which projects?

Comment: @A.DiMatteo  Ex:  Under the main proj, I have different web projects (sub-proj 1,2..) independent of each other. Each of these web projects have sub modules which can be common libs, other web projects which are related. Each of them have their own pom. Main project's pom file has project dependencies and version which could be accessible only if its a direct sub-pom while in the underlying sub-modules, the project version or dependencies aren't resolved during build. Adding more info to question

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use

```
${project.version}
```

to define your parents version, because the child by default inherits the parents version.

Set the parents version with the valid value and not with a property.

If you do so, it should work and you do not have to specify the childs version, as it will be inherited from the parent.